# How can I control ordering of the JSON returned by django REST framwork?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I want to understand at what level code is to be written to control the order returned by the django serializers. Has to to be done at the template level, model level or at the serializer level. What determines the order of fields in the JSON returned by any serializer? In my example, Considering these serializer classes:

```
class FilterURLSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    active = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    inactive = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)


class FacetedFilterOptionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    slug = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    active = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    urls = FilterURLSerializer(read_only=True)


class FacetedFilterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    slug = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    options = FacetedFilterOptionsSerializer(source='options')
```

and this JSON data that is returned:

```
{'name': u'Skill level', 'slug': u'skill', 'options': [{'name': u"I'm Learning", 'slug': u'beginner', 'count': 0, 'active': False, 'urls': {'active': u'/en-US/search?skill=beginner', 'inactive': u'/en-US/search'}}, {'name': u"I'm an Expert", 'slug': u'advanced', 'count': 0, 'active': False, 'urls': {'active': u'/en-US/search?skill=advanced', 'inactive': u'/en-US/search'}}, {'name': u'Intermediate', 'slug': u'intermediate', 'count': 0, 'active': False, 'urls': {'active': u'/en-US/search?skill=intermediate', 'inactive': u'/en-US/search'}}]}
```

I want to know what determines the ordering of those fields in the JSON and how can I change it the way I want?

Comment: JSON objects are unordered, just like Python dictionaries. Why do you need the keys here ordered?

Comment: Have you tried adding `Meta` `fields` list? Fields should be serialized in that order. Note however, that @MartijnPieters's comment applies even though.

Comment: If I have to render the JSON on the frontend such that in 'options field', I want to list 'I'm an expert' field first. How can I do that in other way? In this JSON, 'I'm learning' is the first field in 'options'

Comment: @dhke Exactly my question. Does adding Meta to the models such as ordering = ['name'] determines the JSON? It's an opensource codebase. What I am trying to setup is a custom order that is a little complex. May be I must combine your solution with setting up a queryset in serializers as answered below. Trying it out! :)

Comment: @Pypadds As Martijn stated, the key/value pairs within a JSON object are unordered. In your frontend code, display the values by the key order you want them to be in.

Comment: Whilst it is not a good idea to rely on a particular order in the front end, it is annoying that the data comes out in different orders when manually (human) reading a JSON response.  Anyway it is good practice to specify the fields in the meta section of the serializer.  I would also like to know if this sets the order?

Answer (score 0):

If you want field names ordered you could try the following:

```
myList = list(yourmodel.objects.values('filed1','field2').filter(someid=i).orderby('column'))
```